# Record Contents of a React Native View as a Video

Tags: javascript, react-native, three.js, webgl, expo

I'm trying to build an Audio Visualizer with react native that would render out the visualisation.

I am planing on making the visualisation with three.js and expo.

How do I export the visualisation to a Video ?

Comment: There is no built in way to export anything to video in the browser. You'll need to write your own video creation library or search for one on the net. Note: It's off topic to ask for library recommendations on stack overflow so you'll have to google yourself.